# Direction Installing OpenCL on Linux Mint Dell 9550

Tags: linux, configuration, installation, opencl, linux-mint

I'm about to enter the next phase of a project where I am moving computation to the GPU. Unfortunately, I have had very poor success setting up OpenCL in my environment. I hoped I could garner some specific direction about what implementation of OpenCL to use and how to avoid certain pitfalls upon installation.

My machine:
Linux Mint 17.3
Dell XPS 15 9550 with an Nvidia GTX 960M graphics chip

Some specifics:
I have been unable to find any graphics drivers that work with this hardware other than the Nvidia-352 version found in this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Every other one I try bricks the machine. I've reinstalled Mint more times than I can count finding this one driver. Keep in mind that I must use this configuration for my machine to work.

I attempted to install Nvidia's CUDA toolkit from their site (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and for some reason the installation overwrote my Nvidia-352 driver and bricked the machine again.

At this point Im not certain which implementation is correct anyway. I do not want to try another and have the same thing happen.

Some specific questions:

1. Does every implementation of OpenCL assert itself over the currently installed drivers?
2. If it does then how can I direct my machine to use the correct one?
3. Which implementation would be right for my machine?
4. Can you think of any resources or links that I might be interested in to keep me moving forward? Specifically some installation instructions?

Thanks,

Chronic

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: all this is based on my experience with Ubuntu 15.10, but hopefully Mint isn't too different.

## Does every OpenCL installation overwrite the others?

If you're installing two different vendor's OpenCL implementations then no, they shouldn't overwrite each other. For example, I have Nvidia, Intel CPU, POCL and Beignet (Intel GPU) platforms installed and working. The only caveat is that the Intel CPU runtime overwrote `libOpenCL.so*` files, resulting in a crash in `clinfo` because it required libOpenCL.so.1 which the Intel CPU runtime decided to delete. Re-installing the package `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` fixed this and you can also make `libOpenCL.so.1` a symlink to the actual `.so` file left by the Intel CPU runtime.

If you try installing two versions for the same platform, like you tried, then yes the last one you install will overwrite the previous one. In your case, remember that the CUDA toolkit **also includes the GPU drivers**. I haven't played with the CUDA toolkit in a while, perhaps there is an option to install the toolkit only and not the drivers, but since each toolkit requires a certain minimum driver version, you'd have to pick a toolkit version that works with the driver version you can get installed.

On Ubuntu, there is an `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package you can `sudo apt-get install`. Id doesn't ask to change my drivers, hopefully it will work for you. I don't know what version of the toolkit this one installs.

## Which implementation is right

If you only want to do OpenCL development then install the `nvidia-352` package that worked for you, as well as installing `ocl-icd-opencl-dev`. This package installs the `ocl-icd-libopencl` and `opencl-headers` packages, giving the header files and libOpenCL.so (the ICD loader). You also need to `sudo apt-get install nvidia-opencl-icd-352` as that provides the OpenCL runtime for Nvidia GPUs. If you also want to do CUDA development then you need the toolkit.

As a side note, install one of the CPU runtimes, e.g. POCL, in addition to the Nvidia runtime. I found this useful for detecting a bug in my kernel - the kernel worked most of the time on my Nvidia GPU but failed consistently on POCL. It was a race condition.

## Useful links

Sorry, no up-to-date installation instructions. However, the instructions provided by each vendor with their OpenCL runtime (except Nvidia) seem to be good enough for me.

Here's some older instructions:

- https://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo
- https://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-06-24/install-opencl-on-debianubuntu-orderly/ - The rest of the StreamComputing blog is also interesting.